# How to set inside and outside margins

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx, margins

I am using `python-docx` to create a Word `.docx` in `python` and I would like to set the `inside` and `outside` margins as well as the `gutter`. How to do so?

Given a `section` I can set the left and right margins like this:

```
section.top_margin = Mm(6.6)
section.bottom_margin = Mm(6.6)
```

But how to set the inside and outside ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Mm

# Create a new Document
doc = Document()

# Add a section to the document
section = doc.sections[0]

# Set the top, bottom, left, and right margins
section.top_margin = Mm(6.6)
section.bottom_margin = Mm(6.6)
section.left_margin = Mm(6.6)
section.right_margin = Mm(6.6)

# Set the inside and outside margins
section.inside_margin = Mm(12.7)  # Inside margin (towards the binding)
section.outside_margin = Mm(12.7)  # Outside margin (away from the binding)

# Set the gutter margin (gap between the inside margins of facing pages)
section.gutter = Mm(6.6)

# Save the document
doc.save("your_document.docx")
```

I adjusted the top, bottom, left, and right margins by accessing the **section.top_margin**, **section.bottom_margin**, **section.left_margin**, and **section.right_margin** properties, respectively. To configure the inside and outside margins, I utilized the **section.inside_margin** and **section.outside_margin** properties. Lastly, I specified the gutter margin by utilizing the **section.gutter** property.